# Across languages, do adverbial adpositional phrases ever modify other adpositional phrases?

Tags: syntax, adpositions, modification

In English, I've found examples of two consecutive adverbial prepositional phrases both modifying the rest of a verb group, e.g.,

"He won't go out of the town because of the animals."

"She won't stay in the town because of the people."

I've found examples of two or more adnominal prepositional phrases, the first of which modifies the rest of an NP with the second and subsequent phrases modifying the nominal complement in the previous prepositional phrase. e.g.,

"the bear behind the shed near the rock opposite our garage"

"the squirrels in the branches above the car with those old-fashioned fins"

But I haven't found any example of an adverbial prepositional phrase modifying another prepositional phrase in the same sense that, for example, a word for "strangely" could modify a word for "quickly" in some language other than English to produce a phrase that means "with strange quickness".

I'm asking this question to help me develop my conlang, in which the distinction between adnominal and adverbial prepositional phrases is marked grammatically.

Comment: Just for the record, ‘strangely quickly’ would (or at least could) also mean ‘with strange quickness’ in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Complements versus Modifiers**

Fist of all, it is useful to distinguish preposition phrases (PPs) which occur as Complements from those which occur as Modifiers. Consider the example below:

1. He won't go out of the town because of the animals.

Here the. PP *out of the town* is not a Modifier, but the Locative Complement of the verb *go.* The PP *because of the animals*, in contrast, is a Modifier either of the clause *He won't go out of the town* or, alternatively, of the verb phrase *go out of the town.* The two have different interpretations. The former means the same as:

2. Because of the animals, he won't go out of town.

The latter, where the negation would scope over the *because*-PP would mean the same as:

3. It is not because of the animals that he will go out of town.

So there is no occurrence of one PP modifying another here.

**Prepositions with PP Complements**

Prepositions themselves often take PP Complements:

4. away [from the crowds]
5. down [the road] [from the post office]

**Preposition phrases with PP Modifiers**

There are two main types of PP Modifier within preposition phrase structure in English. We see Modifiers which occur before the Head preposition:

6. I was stationed [over **in France**].

Here *over* must be a Modifier, as *station* specifically licences  *in*-phrases, but not, for example, *to*-phrases:

7. *I was stationed [over **to France**].

According to *The Cambridge grammar of the English language* (Huddleston & Pullum, 2002 p. 645) preposition phrases also occur as post-head Modifier within PP structure:

8. [Downstairs [in the kitchen]] were several other guests.

Here they say that *in the kitchen* is a post-head Modifier of the preposition *downstairs, which they claim can be shown by constituency tests.

So, in short, yes, in at least one language (and one suspects, many others), adposition phrases can appear as Modifiers within a larger adposition phrase.

Comment: It seems noteworthy – and more than a bit suspicious – that every example that might fit the bill here is what would traditionally have been labelled an adverb or a plain preposition, rather than a full PP. Restricting it to ‘traditional PPs’ (preposition + complement), I can’t come up with any examples that don’t just become chains (e.g., ‘down the stairs in the kitchen’ or ‘over the Channel in France’ can hardly be said to be single PPs). I also don’t see why _over_ in _over in France_ must be a modifying PP instead of a modifying preposition?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Just like "we traditionally thought the earth was flat" or "we traditionally kept slaves" or "we traditionally smoked to keep our lungs healthy" aren't good arguments for thinking or doing those things now, thus it is here. Come up with ten good reasons why *over* is an adverb in those examples, and I'll happliy respond to that point ;) I don't believe there to be anything 'suspicious' about saying smoking damages your lungs. In any case OP is already asking from a modern point of view (cf their examples with *because*).

Comment: Not sure how any of that relates to what I said..? I wasn’t suggesting we go back to the traditional terminology, but I’m not sure how to otherwise separate out ‘real’ PPs (by which I mean ones consisting of `preposition + complement`), since most prepositions can be PPs on their own as well. The way I read this question and the earlier one (which seems to have been deleted in favour of this one), the asker was specifically looking for `preposition + complement` PPs, which is exactly the type of structure that _doesn’t_ seem to be allowed to modify other PPs, at least not pre-modify.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That *was* what I thought you were saying, so perhaps I misunderstood. Re the P/PP issue, that just depends where you pay your taxes, as JL would say. I take it that you'd view *all the way over in France* to have a PP *all the way over* in it, given that you don't regard *over* as an adverb? It's quite common, in English, for there to be constraints on pre-head Modifiers. For example, attributive nouns resist plural inflections (though not genitive ones), and adjectives with post-head dependents cannot pre-modify nouns: **an afraid of spiders clown*, for example.

Comment: This sort of stuff is not really my forte, but no, I don’t think I would. I’d consider _in_ to be the head, modified by _all the way_ (sort of pseudo-adverbial NP?) and _over_ (bare preposition), and with _in France_ as its complement. It’s a fair point that there are often restrictions on pre-head modifiers. In this case, it would appear that PPs can modify other PPs _except_ that they can’t have complements. I guess that’s why it feels ‘suspicious’ to me – `preposition + complement` PPs are sort of the archetypal PP.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's not what the post says! *Over* is a modifier within the PP *in France*. In *all the way over in France*, the phrase *all the way* is an NP modifier of *over*, not *in*.  NPs are the most common modifiers of prepositions: *two metres behind the others / five pounds over the odds / twelve paces in front of the king / three weeks before the meeting / a long time after the election* etc, etc, etc. I get the 'suspicious' bit about archetypal NPs (but then modifiers aren't normally archetypal Xes!)

Comment: I’m not really sure how to properly constituency-test it, but to me, it ‘feels’ like `[[all the way] [over] in France]`, rather than `[[[all the way] over] in France]`. We can remove either modifier and still maintain structure and meaning (‘all the way in France / over in France’), which indicates parallel modifiers to me. How would you test for modifier nestedness, other than inability to remove either separately?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "I was stationed all the way in France" doesn't mean anything intelligible to me. In fact, for me, it's ungrammatical!

Comment: It’s less likely than the version with _over_, but it’s perfectly grammatical to me. A fair number of hits for the phrase in Google as well (even discounting the ones that are about some sports team ‘going all the way in France’, which is obviously different).